# Getting MAX value of one field based on 2nd field in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables "room" & "building"

I am trying to get the max(roomPrice) AS "Total Building Price" grouped by building name. I know there should be a sub-query to get the values from roomPrice, so the max(roomprice) will work, but I just can not get that right.

```
Table1 ( roomNo, buildingNo, roomType, roomPrice )
Table2 ( buildingNo, buldingName, buildingCity )
```

Sorry just started in SQL and books do not tell all.

Comment: can you attached your table definition @Wombat?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
select a.buildingNo,b.buildingName,b.buildingCity ,a.max_room_price from
(select buildingNo,max(roomPrice) as max_room_price from table1 GROUP BY buildingNo) as a

LEFT JOIN
(select buildingNo, buildingName,buildingCity from table2)as b
on a.buildingNo = b. buildingNo
```

This one works fine according to the output you want.
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well:

```
SELECT t2.buildingName as 'Building Name', MAX(t1.roomPrice) AS 'Total Building Price'
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.buildingNo = t2.buldingNo
GROUP BY t2.buildingName
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT tab1.buildingNo, MAX(tab1.roomPrice)
FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.buildingNo = tab2.buildingNo
GROUP BY  tab1.buildingNo
```

if you want a sum over a whole building, use this

```
SELECT tab1.buildingNo, SUM(tab1.roomPrice)
FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.buildingNo = tab2.buildingNo
GROUP BY  tab1.buildingNo
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/143c2/6

`JOIN` combine every row of one Table with all rows of a other Table. If you add a condition with `ON` you can reduce the combinations you get. In this case only rows with the same `buildingNo` on both tables will be "glued" together. And then we group them by this `buildingNo` and only take the row with the `MAX` of `roomPrice` or simply create the `SUM`.

Comment: Yes i see it works but I forgot to mention that each building has 3 or more rooms so they have to be added together for each building before the max generated. Sorry

Comment: Ok, this is an important fact good to know :)
Let's see what i can do ...

Comment: Replace `MAX` with `SUM`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table #Table2(buildingNo int, buldingName nvarchar(50), buildingCity    varchar(50))
  Insert into #Table2 values
  (1,'A','Delhi'),
  (2,'B','Delhi')


   Create Table #Table1  (roomNo int, buildingNo int, roomType  varchar(50), roomPrice int)
   Insert into #Table1 values
   (1,1,'2BHK',50000),
   (2,2,'2BHK',60000),
  (3,1,'1BHK',55000),
  (4,2,'2BHK',65000),
  (4,1,'2BHK',80000),
   (4,2,'2BHK',90000)

 SELECT max(roomPrice) AS [Total Building Price],buldingName FROM #Table1  t1
    JOIN  #Table2 t2
    ON t1.buildingNo=t2.buildingNo
    group by buldingName
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a sub-query if you only need to know max(roomPrice):

```
SELECT tab2.buildingName, max(tab1.roomPrice) AS TotalBuildingPrice
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON tab1.buildingNo = tab2.buildingNo
GROUP BY tab2.buildingName
```

However as your question indicates total building price, you might actually mean max(sum()) :

```
SELECT tab2.buildingName, sum(tab1.roomPrice) AS TotalBuildingPrice
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON tab1.buildingNo = tab2.buildingNo
GROUP BY tab2.buildingName
ORDER BY TotalBuildingPrice DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Ok building 1 has 3 rooms adding to a max roomprice of 2700.00 and those 3 rooms have to be added to give a max per building and same for 2 and 3 with different values. I don't know if I am explaining it right.